# Probability of Seating

Tags: probability, statistics

Three couples (each couple being a male and female) are randomly seated in a row. What is the probability that the seating arrangement ends up with
(c) all couples are seated together? at least Three digits after the decimal

What I am thinking so far:

number of different seating : 6!

couples sitting together : 3!

(6!)/(3!*3!) = 20

20/6! = 0.028

Probability the couples are sitting together is 2.8%?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure where your computation $6!/(3!3!)$ came from.

The number of ways to seat three couples in a row is $3!$ as you noted. Then you just need to account for the seating within each couple (is the male on the left or on the right?). For each couple there are two ways to switch the seating, so the numerator should be $3!\cdot 2^3$.

Comment: so the probability is 6.7%, thanks.

Comment: How would the probability change if they are seated around a round table. Would it be `13.4%`?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve the problem, which makes it easier to compute the result, is this:

We can start with any person. The probability of having their partner sitting next to them is $\frac{1}{5}$. We can then follow with any person out of the 4 remaining. Now the probability of having their partner sit next to them is $\frac{1}{3}$ (1 out of 3 remaining people). Lastly, the final couple will be matched already (if we have matched the other two couples).

So the probability is simply $\frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{15} \approx 6.7\%$